# How to memory profile unit tests running in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, api, unit-testing, nunit, memory-profiling

I'd like to create unit tests that test whether instances of specific types (not written by me) are being created; whether they are live or on the GC heap, etc - the kind of thing the .Net profiler API allows profilers to do via C++. These tests need to be run from Visual Studio via the NUnit test adapter for Visual Studio.

However, I have not found any built-in or third party C# API that will allow me to do this.

The SciTech memory profiler API comes close, but it [does not seem to allow](http://forum.memprofiler.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2879&p=4461&hilit=api+visual+studio#p4461) profiling running tests in Visual Studio. Instead, it requires that the unit test runner process be run under the profiler.

Comment: Looks like ReSharper dotMemory can do this: https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/unit/

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the following options:

1. https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/unit/
2. https://memprofiler.com/automate-memory-testing[2](https://memprofiler.com/automate-memory-testing)